# Libgdx is stand alone project?

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to develop an android game with libGdx.
My question is, is it possible to integrate the code in another project. like a module or another app?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine so.  I've combined Libgdx and JSwing to make a level editor before.

Answer (score -1):

**No you can't**. You need to create project for Libgdx seperately using **gdx-setup.jar**. Then if you want to reuse your existing Android project you can do it by copying classes. But again it is not good code practices for Libgdx programmer. Because in libgdx most things need to be done on Libgdx layer. Only the functionality that needs native platform and are not possible on libgdx need to do on libgdx layer.

For details : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: It is certainly possible to use libgdx in another project. Whether it is practical or the best choice depends on the use-case, but that's not the question.